# Meaning of new sub-entry added to the Oxford English Dictionary: “to have off”

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I checked out the recent [updates](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/march-2015-update/new-words-list-march-2015/) to the OED (Oxford English Dictionary) and noticed a new verb *to have off* that I couldn't figure out the exact meaning of.

My questions are:

1. Is *to have off* have the same meaning as *to have away*?
2. Can anyone tell me the usage of *to have off* in “real” English?

Note: I already know the meaning of [*to have it off*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=have%20it%20off).

Comment: Please stop putting spaces before sentence-ending punctuation in English.  Also, please avoid over-formatting.

Comment: Well, [ODO answers this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have-it-away-or-off?q=have+it+off), I think. OED has a bit more historical data, but ODO certainly lists the current prevailing meaning.

Comment: @AndrewLeach AFAIK. *to have it off* and *to have off* have different meanings (they certainly do in the U.S.).

Comment: This question needs to be reframed to clarify the question. A standard google search of [*have off*](https://www.google.com/search?q=have+off+meaning&oq=have+off+meaning&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.5927j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) and [*have away*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=have+away+meaning), both direct to the sexual definition only.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The OED shows *have it off* with two meanings, one of which means *to have sexual intercourse* and the other meaning associated with success in a criminal enterprise. But the OED does not have an entry for *have off* and I'm struggling to think of a context, other than e.g. *had the day off*.

Comment: "the OED does not have an entry for have off". @WS2 please check [this](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/march-2015-update/new-words-list-march-2015/#new_sub_entries)

Comment: @WS2 Not a main entry, no; but it is a newly added subentry under _have_. All the examples are of the phrase _to have it off_ meaning ‘steal’ or ‘have sex’. The other sense (‘having the day off’) is to be found under [_off_, 4.d.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130563).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes. what I said was possibly misleading. In the OED *have off* is shown as a sub-category, but with no explanation that is separate from what it describes as the colloquial *have it off*.  It also says that it is rare in the US. I am more intrigued by RBarry Young's assertion that *have off* has a different meaning to *have it off* in the US.

Comment: @tchrist, the only rational reason I see for not having a space before sentence-ending punctuation is to avoid wrapping before the punctuation. Anything else seems to be more a matter of aesthetics, taste and tradition. Personally I prefer having a space before any cap-height character because it makes punctuation more visible. Hello NSA & FBI... now you can infer my identity with this preference.

Answer (score 1):

OED's entry for ***to have off,*** as of March 2015, is (abridged):

> **to have off**
>
> 1. *trans. colloq.* **to have it off** rare in U.S. use.
>
>    a. Criminals' slang. To successfully carry out a crime, esp. a robbery or burglary. Cf. sense 3. Now *rare.*
>
>    > 1977   ‘E. Crispin’ *Glimpses of Moon* xii. 235   He had had it off all right, thanks..to making careful reccys.
>
>    b. To have sexual intercourse (with a person). Cf. sense 2.
>
>    > 1982   M. Leigh *Goose-pimples* ii, in *Abigail's Party & Goose-pimples* (1983) 151,   I know about you two. I know you've been having it off.
> 2. *trans. colloq.* To have sexual intercourse with. Cf. sense 1b. *rare.*
>
>    > 1970   *Irish Times* 5 June 7/2   He had her off at that time probably in his hotel at Dungloe, or he had her in a caravan at Bundoran.
> 3. *trans. colloq.* To steal (something); to rob (a person). Cf. sense 1a.
>
>    > 2004   G. Johnson *Powder Wars* (2005) iii. 32   I'd got into robbing wagons... Mostly they were parked up and we'd just have them off. Sell the vehicle.

The following applies to [british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english).

All of thoses senses are common to *have it away,* and in almost all cases *off* can be replaced with *away*. The quote in 1b (→ "I know you've been having it away") sounds rather quaint. *Having it off* generally refers to sex and is rather more vulgar than *having it away.* When referring to stealing, *have it away* is more easily understood than *off*.

*Have it off* is almost always sexual. *Have it away* is usually non-sexual unless the context allows that.

As OED notes, both forms are at best colloquial; in my experience *have [it] off* is rather more vulgar than using *away*.

Comment: Has *to have it off* the same meaning as *to have off*?

Comment: Yes; but *to have off* as a phrasal verb is rare, unless one says "I have next week off," when it means "away from work" -- even then the idea of "stealing" that time for yourself is not entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the phrases *[have it off](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have-it-away-or-off?q=have%20off)* and *[have it away](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have-it-away-or-off?q=have%20off)* have the same definition on ODO:

> British vulgar slang Have sexual intercourse.

Macmillan concurs:

> *[have it off](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/have-off)* (with someone)
>   to have sex with someone
>
> *[have it away](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/have-away)* (with someone)
>   to have sex with someone

Three's a charm with Cambridge:

> [have it off](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/have-it-off)
>   (also have it away) UK slang
>   to have sex:
>   He was having it off
>   with his friend's wife.

Comment: The OP was asking about *to have off*, not *to have it off*.  AFAIK, they are different.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I’m not aware of _to have off_ meaning **anything** as an intransitive phrasal verb. _To have off_ is the main subentry in the OED that the asker is referring to, because entries are always given with no arguments; but the only examples given are transitive, with generic dummy objects (as in _have it off_). The meaning in _having time off_ is found under [_off_, 4.d.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130563): “Away or free from one's work, school, service, etc.” and that’s not normally a phrasal verb.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet As I pointed out in the comments to my answer, this usage is very common in the U.S.  In fact, in my experience, it is more common than the more formal versions you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "*I have off* " means that I have time-off from work.  It's usually expressed like: "*She has off next week.*"

Comment: Or "She has next week off".  This does exist in the US.

Comment: Would you really ever say, “She has off next week”? That sounds _extremely_ wrong to me, and I would probably assume if I saw it written that the writer was a non-native speaker. I have never heard it used as a phrasal verb. I would either say, “She has next week off” or “She is off next week”.

Comment: @Janus Perhaps the MWV is marginally non-mandatorily separable for very weighty objects (She has off alternate Fridays for the months of May, June, August and November, together with the fourth Thursday in every month.) But then again ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Even then, just … no. “She has alternate Fridays off for the months of May, June…”, no problem; but I simply cannot force my brain not to bat its internal eyelashes at the other version.

Comment: Quite a few relevant Google hits for "she has off every".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, very much so.  I have both heard it and said many, many times in my life.  It is *very* common.  And FWIW, it sounds a hundred times better to my ear than "*I had it off with the ex*".

Comment: And I can assure you that in the U.S., if you said "*I had off with my kids last week.*"  *everyone* will assume that you were on vacation with your family and ***not*** that they should call child services to have you arrested.